# ForkJoinTask:fork method execution

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

From Javadoc for ForkJoinTask::fork method:

> Arranges to asynchronously execute this task in the pool the current
> task is running in....

So when we invoke fork method on a ForkJoinTask, does it start executing the task or just prepares the infrastructure needed, waiting for some other method to be called for actual execution to happen?

Comment: The answer can be found in the [documentatin of the `ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html): "*A ForkJoinPool differs from other kinds of ExecutorService mainly by virtue of employing work-stealing: all threads in the pool attempt to find and execute tasks submitted to the pool and/or created by other active tasks (eventually blocking waiting for work if none exist).*"

Comment: In essence: a task is either a "splitable" task or a "non-splitable" task. The execution of a "splttable" task is reduced to create more tasks. The execution of a "non-splittable" task creates a (partial) result. The overall result of the execution is then some reduction of the partial results.